# How do I optimize schemaDocument.Namespaces code for performance?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I have this code that is called thousands of times and I need to optimize it for performance.
I thought about caching xmlQualifiedNames but it's not good enough.
any ideas ?

```
    private static string GetPrefixForNamespace(string ns,  XmlSchema schemaDocument)
    {
        string prefix = null;
         XmlQualifiedName[] xmlQualifiedNames = schemaDocument.Namespaces.ToArray();
        foreach (XmlQualifiedName qn in xmlQualifiedNames)
        {
            if (ns == qn.Namespace)
            {
                prefix = qn.Name;
                break;
            }
        }

        return prefix;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're looking for strings (`Namespace`) inside the `xmlQualifiedNames`, how about caching those?

Or using LINQ to search in them?

Or - depending on the kind of input you get - using memoization to speed up your calls (really just fancy caching) [like in this article.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227165553/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/26/function-memoization.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Stuff it in a `Dictionary` or `Hashtable` or even a some caching mechanism.